# How do I get access to localhost:3000 on OS X on a network using a windows machine?

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion

I used to access localhost:3000 serving up an application via [computername].local:3000 
The recent update of Mountain Lion removed Web Sharing

I have installed the Web Sharing preference pane found here http://clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion/

but alas I'm still not able to access it from Windows XP on ie7

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for other computers to be able to access it, they need to know where it is.

This is where the "hosts" file comes in.

On your Windows XP machine, open up notepad as an administrator. From notepad, click "File" > "Open" in the top menu.

Now open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

The file should look something similar to what I've pasted below:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Now, add the local IP address of your OSX machine with the hostname you want to access it by in the browser. You can find out your Mac's local IP address in the Network preferences pane (instructions can be found here: http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/21/find-ip-address-mac/ )

Example (assuming your Mac's IP on the local network is 192.168.0.100):

```
192.168.0.100    [computername].local
```

Save the file. Now your Windows XP machine will know that, in order to access [computername].local, it will need to contact the computer at 192.168.0.100

Assuming your web server is online, and configured to accept connections on port 3000, you can open up a web browser on Windows XP and type http://[computername].local:3000

If you still can't access it, also try the following and update your question with the results:

1. Temporarily disable the Firewall on OSX. Does this allow Windows XP to access it?
2. What error message do you get from Windows XP?